# Browsing Core-Data Contents During Runtime (via Xcode simulator)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios-simulator

I've written an application that uses Core-Data.  I'm wondering if, while the XCode simulator is running, there is a way to see the contents held via Core-Data (the various rows, attributes, etc).  Would greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You can do this if you are using a sqlite store but you probably shouldn't. Core Data isn't SQL and how it serializes objects in the store has very little to do with how the live objects behave in memory. You're more likely to confuse yourself that get a clear picture of what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Using SQLite as the persistent store I usually fire up [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58), navigate to the [application directory](http://richard.giliam.net/?p=13), and refresh the tables/rerun queries as needed.